# python sdk hyperledger connection throughs "failed to connect to all addresses"

Tags: python, docker, sdk, hyperledger-fabric, grpc

I am facing a problem while connecting to an hyperledger network from a docker container.
I have Hyperledger fabric 1.4 installed on a virtual machine in which I have a docker container with a fabric python sdk.
I added crypto-config and a network.json which describes the network nodes in my project directory.
I also added peers address to the /etc/hosts file.
I am facing this problem while trying to execute this script:

```
import asyncio
from hfc.fabric import Client

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
cli = Client(net_profile="network.json")
org1_admin = cli.get_user('org1.example.com', 'Admin')
cli.new_channel('mychannel')
gopath='/shared/test_notaire/Hyperledger/fabric-samples/first-network/crypto-config'

# Query Peer installed chaincodes, make sure the chaincode is installed
response = loop.run_until_complete(cli.query_installed_chaincodes(
               requestor=org1_admin,
               peers=['peer0.org1.example.com'],
               decode=False
               ))

"""
# An example response:

chaincodes {
  name: "example_cc"
  version: "v1.0"
  path: "github.com/example_cc"
  id: "\374\361\027j(\332\225\367\253\030\242\303U&\356\326\241\2003|\033\266:\314\250\032\254\221L#\006G"
}
"""

# Query Peer Joined channel
response = loop.run_until_complete(cli.query_channels(
               requestor=org1_admin,
               peers=['peer0.org1.example.com'],
               decode=True
               ))

"""
# An example response:

channels {
  channel_id: "channel1"
}
"""
```

but I am getting this error:

```
Init client with profile=network.json
create org with name=orderer.example.com
create org with name=org1.example.com
create org with name=org2.example.com
create ca with name=ca-org1
create ca with name=ca-org2
Import orderers = dict_keys(['orderer.example.com'])
Import peers = dict_keys(['peer0.org1.example.com', 'peer1.org1.example.com', 'peer0.org2.example.com', 'peer1.org2.example.com'])
New channel with name = mychannel
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 14, in <module>
    decode=False
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/asyncio/base_events.py", line 488, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "/code/hfc/fabric/client.py", line 1618, in query_installed_chaincodes
    responses = await asyncio.gather(*responses)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/aiogrpc/channel.py", line 40, in __call__
    return await fut
grpc._channel._MultiThreadedRendezvous: <_MultiThreadedRendezvous of RPC that terminated with:
        status = StatusCode.UNAVAILABLE
        details = "failed to connect to all addresses"
        debug_error_string = "{"created":"@1619428329.913177037","description":"Failed to pick subchannel","file":"src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/client_channel.cc","file_line":3940,"referenced_errors":[{"created":"@1619428329.913167398","description":"failed to connect to all addresses","file":"src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/lb_policy/pick_first/pick_first.cc","file_line":392,"grpc_status":14}]}"
```

I also can't ping or nslookup peers from the container.

Comment: Please either augment images of text with the text it contains, or replace the image with the text. The reason for this is that images are not searchable, accessible, or easy to read on small screens.

Comment: The usual suspect in this case is to check if your server support HTTP/2. Not sure about Python but .NET must run another 'proxy' tool that could translate from HTTP/2 to HTTP